# Appcelerator push notifications without arrow

Tags: push-notification, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I've build a (android and iOS) app with Appcelerator. One of the main features of the app is a list of news. These news posts are managed in a Wordpress website. The app retrieve the news post via a XML feed. I want to build a feature the give the users of the app a push notification for certain news posts. One of the requirements is that the push notifications are also managed in the Wordpress site.

When the user of the app click/slide the push notification the app has to open and open the news post the push notification is for.

My question(s):

Is it possible to send push notifications directly from the Wordpress site?

Is it possible to open the news post when the user clicks/slide the push notification?

Can anyone get me started. The only thing I find is how to implement Appcelerator own Arrow push notification service.